# nunit automatic test generator vs2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, plugins, nunit

Is there a good free plugin for generating a template for Nunit test for visual studio 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a Visual Studio file/project template, that generates boilerplate code for declaring a test fixture and unit tests?  If so, you can create your own by modifying the files located in *VisualStudioInstallDir\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033* and *VisualStudioInstallDir\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp*, or by following [this tutorial](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/10/17/creating-visual-studio-project-templates.html).

Note: replace CSharp\1033 with the programming language and locale installed on your system.

If you are looking for a tool that generates unit tests for you, I would start by looking at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) from Microsoft Research.